# Why the program exit functions does not work except in release mode

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, exit

My question as in the title.

I have used many function to exit the program in the `debug mode` like:

```
QApplication::quit();
QApplication::exit();
qApp->exit();
exit(0)
```

But does not ends the program.
If you in the `release mode`, all the previous functions works fine.

**Why these functions does not work except in release mode ?**

I called it from:

[image]

Comment: Where do you call these functions? Do you call them after starting the eventloop?

Comment: `QApplication::*` calls make sense only after `QApplication::exec()`, btw.

Comment: @Nejat: Look at my question again at the bottom, I have updated.

Comment: @vahancho: I have updated my question. look at my question again at the bottom to know from where I called these functions.

Comment: @LionKing, if the application does not exit, what happens? Your Gui stay open, gui closed or what? Are you sure your `on_actionExit_triggered()` slot called in debug mode?

Comment: @vahancho: `if the application does not exit, what happens`: does not happen anything, and gui stay open. `Are you sure your on_actionExit_triggered() slot called in debug mode?` I think the reason here,  but why the slot does not called in debug mode, and works fine in release mode.

Comment: @LionKing, check your project configuration. Clean up your project, remove all moc files, run qmake again and compile the project from scratch in debug mode.

Comment: @vahancho: Unfortunately the problem still exists after doing all you said.

Comment: @LionKing, than your signal/slot is broken in debug mode. The problem is not in `QApplication::quit()` but in that your slot is not called.

Comment: Thank you every one, and `@vahancho` for help. the problem was solved. but I'm still don't know what the reason

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow:

1. Clean the project
2. Run qmake
3. Rebuild and run

Make sure all the steps are done in debug mode.